# Non-Isentropic Turbine

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

comparing to an Isentropic turbine
I was wondering if you could help me answer a question I coulnd't find the answer to.
If I have a non Isentropic Turbine... why doesn't the pressure difference between intake and outtake doesnt change? (be pressure difference I mean, for e.g if intake is P1 and outtake is P2.. then P2-P1).

on the other hand, enthalpy, entropy and temperature do change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a power plant, you *control* the inlet and outlet pressures to the turbine.  The outlet pressure is controlled by controlling the temperature in the condenser, and the inlet pressure is controlled by controlling the pressure exiting the pump, plus the amount of heat added to the working fluid after it passes through the pump.  The other variables you mentioned respond to how close to isentropic the turbine operates.

Comment: So basically, Pressures on intake and outtake are independent of each other?

Comment: Sure, if you are controlling them independently.